# Postgresql Difficulties on open a backup

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have an app with Node.JS where I have Sequelize to manage my database created in Postegresql on my vps.
I'm trying to backup the database with the command:

```
pg_dump dbname -U user -h 127.0.0.1 -f > db.sql
```

Then it asks the password that, in my case, I have set on Sequelize on the app and it creates a backup.
But when I try to open it on my pc, for exemple in DB Browser, it asks the key where I insert the password for the database, the user password for psql (which is the same) and the vps password but nothing happens. It does not open the database. What am I doing wrong?

In order to create user and database on psql I used this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04

Thank you

Comment: You're trying to open the dump file? I've never tried to view one personally but what I have done is taken the dump file and reloaded it onto another db or to replace the existing one with the backup. `psql -U user -h host -d dbname < db.sql` I don't think you need the `-f` argument either.